# How do I correctly parse JSON in R?

Tags: r, json, twitter

I'm trying to convert twitter data to a data frame, but keep getting:

```
Error in parse_con(txt, bigint_as_char) : 
  parse error: after array element, I expect ',' or ']'
          etweeted":false,"lang":"es"} {"created_at":"Fri Feb 01 05:54
                     (right here) ------^
```

Tried using stream_in instead but secondary columns aren't working right.

My code:

```
try2 <- fromJSON("/Users/malana/Downloads/tweets.20130201_055232.10000lines", flatten=TRUE)
```

JSON file looks like:

```
{"created_at":"Fri Feb 01 05:54:47 +0000 2013","id":297221438333652992,"id_str":"297221438333652992","text":"RT @iEnterate: Por lo general, aquellos que reprimen la ira tienen tendencia a ser violentos despu\u00e9s de beber.","source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/blackberry.com\/twitter\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTwitter for BlackBerry\u00ae\u003c\/a\u003e","truncated":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":1055846485,"id_str":"1055846485","name":"Arturo Cameras Lara","screen_name":"CamerasLara","location":"Tapachula Chiapas","url":null,"description":"Gran visi\u00f3n para el futuro, empezar desde hoy el sistema empresarial, para llegar a lo grande, con instinto pol\u00edtico en futuro. PRI. ","protected":false,"followers_count":41,"friends_count":72,"listed_count":0,"created_at":"Wed Jan 02 18:56:40 +0000 2013","favourites_count":14,"utc_offset":null,"time_zone":null,"geo_enabled":true,"verified":false,"statuses_count":1872,"lang":"es","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"profile_background_color":"C0DEED","profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/a0.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png","profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/si0.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png","profile_background_tile":false,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/a0.twimg.com\/profile_images\/3172272497\/1e624e13eb43b3cc47049b494c757d98_normal.jpeg","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/si0.twimg.com\/profile_images\/3172272497\/1e624e13eb43b3cc47049b494c757d98_normal.jpeg","profile_banner_url":"https:\/\/si0.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/1055846485\/1357160274","profile_link_color":"0084B4","profile_sidebar_border_color":"C0DEED","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"DDEEF6","profile_text_color":"333333","profile_use_background_image":true,"default_profile":true,"default_profile_image":false,"following":null,"follow_request_sent":null,"notifications":null},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"retweeted_status":{"created_at":"Thu Jan 31 17:01:13 +0000 2013","id":297026763945549824,"id_str":"297026763945549824","text":"Por lo general, aquellos que reprimen la ira tienen tendencia a ser violentos despu\u00e9s de beber.","source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/www.hootsuite.com\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eHootSuite\u003c\/a\u003e","truncated":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":385621677,"id_str":"385621677","name":"\u00a1Ent\u00e9rate!","screen_name":"iEnterate","location":"iEnterate@gmail.com","url":null,"description":"\u00a1Ent\u00e9rate de lo m\u00e1s actual! Ciencia,historia, tecnolog\u00eda,salud, psicolog\u00eda, citas, C u r i o s i d a d e s, Deportes. \u00a1Disfruta!","protected":false,"followers_count":253729,"friends_count":46,"listed_count":557,"created_at":"Wed Oct 05 20:33:20 +0000 2011","favourites_count":1595,"utc_offset":-36000,"time_zone":"Hawaii","geo_enabled":false,"verified":false,"statuses_count":17030,"lang":"es","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"profile_background_color":"EDF4F7","profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/a0.twimg.com\/profile_background_images\/753934440\/26f50f5fc7cc2f774bdba1bb7c3c0602.jpeg","profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/si0.twimg.com\/profile_background_images\/753934440\/26f50f5fc7cc2f774bdba1bb7c3c0602.jpeg","profile_background_tile":true,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/a0.twimg.com\/profile_images\/2712142543\/81d9ec6c938b23cfb98cda090a281aa9_normal.jpeg","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/si0.twimg.com\/profile_images\/2712142543\/81d9ec6c938b23cfb98cda090a281aa9_normal.jpeg","profile_banner_url":"https:\/\/si0.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/385621677\/1357540686","profile_link_color":"0084B4","profile_sidebar_border_color":"FFFFFF","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"DDEEF6","profile_text_color":"333333","profile_use_background_image":true,"default_profile":false,"default_profile_image":false,"following":null,"follow_request_sent":null,"notifications":null},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"retweet_count":146,"entities":{"hashtags":[],"urls":[],"user_mentions":[]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":true,"lang":"es"},"retweet_count":0,"entities":{"hashtags":[],"urls":[],"user_mentions":[{"screen_name":"iEnterate","name":"\u00a1Ent\u00e9rate!","id":385621677,"id_str":"385621677","indices":[3,13]}]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"lang":"es"}
{"created_at":"Fri Feb 01 05:54:47 +0000 2013","id":297221438337867776,"id_str":"297221438337867776","text":"RT @nolavoy: Asi que armate uno armate un Hern\u00e1n \u266a","source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/twitter.com\/download\/iphone\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTwitter for iPhone\u003c\/a\u003e","truncated":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":207797664,"id_str":"207797664","name":"Bazinga","screen_name":"ferchug22","location":"","url":null,"description":"No llores por quien no te ama , ama a quien llora por ti \u266a. fan de holasoygerman Pastii , Bionico , NTVG\ue022","protected":false,"followers_count":28,"friends_count":238,"listed_count":0,"created_at":"Tue Oct 26 01:46:23 +0000 2010","favourites_count":4,"utc_offset":-10800,"time_zone":"Buenos Aires","geo_enabled":false,"verified":false,"statuses_count":261,"lang":"es","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"profile_background_color":"C0DEED","profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/a0.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png","profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/si0.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png","profile_background_tile":false,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/a0.twimg.com\/profile_images\/1825125711\/las_pastillas_normal.jpg","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/si0.twimg.com\/profile_images\/1825125711\/las_pastillas_normal.jpg","profile_link_color":"0084B4","profile_sidebar_border_color":"C0DEED","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"DDEEF6","profile_text_color":"333333","profile_use_background_image":true,"default_profile":true,"default_profile_image":false,"following":null,"follow_request_sent":null,"notifications":null},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"retweeted_status":{"created_at":"Fri Feb 01 03:22:45 +0000 2013","id":297183175455690753,"id_str":"297183175455690753","text":"Asi que armate uno armate un Hern\u00e1n \u266a","source":"web","truncated":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":842643985,"id_str":"842643985","name":"No La Voy","screen_name":"nolavoy","location":"C\u00f3rdoba","url":"http:\/\/nolavoy.blogspot.com.ar","description":"El futbol es una joda, nuestro humor es cosa seria. Humildes y con muchos huevos. Campeones Tweets Awards 2012 terna Humor en 140 caracteres.","protected":false,"followers_count":25778,"friends_count":182,"listed_count":45,"created_at":"Mon Sep 24 00:13:39 +0000 2012","favourites_count":4929,"utc_offset":-10800,"time_zone":"Brasilia","geo_enabled":true,"verified":false,"statuses_count":16997,"lang":"es","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"profile_background_color":"030E14","profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/a0.twimg.com\/profile_background_images\/720721348\/b41f8d6d71cb21f42aaaa7c8ef6e6add.jpeg","profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/si0.twimg.com\/profile_background_images\/720721348\/b41f8d6d71cb21f42aaaa7c8ef6e6add.jpeg","profile_background_tile":true,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/a0.twimg.com\/profile_images\/2886958628\/6c32bef218d4cd7f0032909a8f53cd94_normal.jpeg","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/si0.twimg.com\/profile_images\/2886958628\/6c32bef218d4cd7f0032909a8f53cd94_normal.jpeg","profile_banner_url":"https:\/\/si0.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/842643985\/1351510749","profile_link_color":"3E08F2","profile_sidebar_border_color":"000000","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"DDEEF6","profile_text_color":"333333","profile_use_background_image":true,"default_profile":false,"default_profile_image":false,"following":null,"follow_request_sent":null,"notifications":null},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"retweet_count":35,"entities":{"hashtags":[],"urls":[],"user_mentions":[]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":true,"lang":"es"},"retweet_count":0,"entities":{"hashtags":[],"urls":[],"user_mentions":[{"screen_name":"nolavoy","name":"No La Voy","id":842643985,"id_str":"842643985","indices":[3,11]}]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"lang":"es"}
{"created_at":"Fri Feb 01 05:54:47 +0000 2013","id":297221438312701953,"id_str":"297221438312701953","text":"#SometimesYouHaveTo Move on with life","source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/twitter.com\/download\/iphone\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTwitter for iPhone\u003c\/a\u003e","truncated":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":724874196,"id_str":"724874196","name":"Morgan\u270c\u2764","screen_name":"MorganAuderer","location":"","url":null,"description":"If nothing goes right, go left. \n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nIowa","protected":false,"followers_count":212,"friends_count":205,"listed_count":0,"created_at":"Mon Jul 30 00:02:45 +0000 2012","favourites_count":716,"utc_offset":null,"time_zone":null,"geo_enabled":false,"verified":false,"statuses_count":1298,"lang":"en","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"profile_background_color":"0099B9","profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/a0.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme4\/bg.gif","profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/si0.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme4\/bg.gif","profile_background_tile":false,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/a0.twimg.com\/profile_images\/3162469229\/752f4a8a2b3a97125ceb9acdc15e4c42_normal.jpeg","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/si0.twimg.com\/profile_images\/3162469229\/752f4a8a2b3a97125ceb9acdc15e4c42_normal.jpeg","profile_banner_url":"https:\/\/si0.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/724874196\/1359354683","profile_link_color":"0099B9","profile_sidebar_border_color":"5ED4DC","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"95E8EC","profile_text_color":"3C3940","profile_use_background_image":true,"default_profile":false,"default_profile_image":false,"following":null,"follow_request_sent":null,"notifications":null},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"retweet_count":0,"entities":{"hashtags":[{"text":"SometimesYouHaveTo","indices":[0,19]}],"urls":[],"user_mentions":[]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"lang":"en"}
{"created_at":"Fri Feb 01 05:54:47 +0000 2013","id":297221438308507649,"id_str":"297221438308507649","text":"@nacchanx2_n \u3084\u3070\u304b\u3063\u305f\u3067\u7b11","source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/twitter.com\/download\/android\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTwitter for Android\u003c\/a\u003e","truncated":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":297188576653869057,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":"297188576653869057","in_reply_to_user_id":1006505846,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":"1006505846","in_reply_to_screen_name":"nacchanx2_n","user":{"id":982494234,"id_str":"982494234","name":"\u3055\u304d\u3093\u3061\u3087","screen_name":"sakincho_s2","location":"","url":null,"description":null,"protected":false,"followers_count":50,"friends_count":47,"listed_count":0,"created_at":"Sat Dec 01 13:04:03 +0000 2012","favourites_count":6,"utc_offset":null,"time_zone":null,"geo_enabled":false,"verified":false,"statuses_count":141,"lang":"ja","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"profile_background_color":"C0DEED","profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/a0.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png","profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/si0.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png","profile_background_tile":false,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/a0.twimg.com\/profile_images\/3055034572\/b4a412b50cccc012194bb91e6ec932e0_normal.jpeg","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/si0.twimg.com\/profile_images\/3055034572\/b4a412b50cccc012194bb91e6ec932e0_normal.jpeg","profile_link_color":"0084B4","profile_sidebar_border_color":"C0DEED","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"DDEEF6","profile_text_color":"333333","profile_use_background_image":true,"default_profile":true,"default_profile_image":false,"following":null,"follow_request_sent":null,"notifications":null},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"retweet_count":0,"entities":{"hashtags":[],"urls":[],"user_mentions":[{"screen_name":"nacchanx2_n","name":"\u306a\u3063\u3061\u3083\u3093","id":1006505846,"id_str":"1006505846","indices":[0,12]}]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"lang":"ja"}
```

EDIT:
I added the brackets to the beginning and end of the JSON file based on another search but without them, I get this error:

```
Error in parse_con(txt, bigint_as_char) : parse error: trailing garbage
          etweeted":false,"lang":"es"} {"created_at":"Fri Feb 01 05:54
                     (right here) ------^
```

Comment: Hi Malana! This appears to be invalid JSON - see jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com - did you forget to include the end of it?

Comment: Is that partial JSON string from that **exact**  file, opened as a text,  that triggered included error? Error seems to be generated when NDJSON file was opened with `fromJSON()`,  in NDJSON there are  multiple JSON objects, one per each line,  `fromJSON()` is expected to fail with such input and `stream_in()` should be used instead. But that included file sample starts with a `[` so it seems to be a JSON array.  So some reproducible data would be appreciated (i.e. couple of complete lines in case it actually is NDJSON).

Comment: And please consider describing/including output from `stream_in()` and how it differs from expected results; we don't really know what  _"secondary columns aren't working right"_  might mean for you (is flattening not working, does it not follow expected logic, is it actually flattening you are after?)

Comment: Mark, I only included an excerpt since it is a very large file.

Comment: When I use stream in, I get a df but cannot inspect it, I get this error "Error in View : 'names' attribute [1] must be the same length as the vector [0]"
If I specify specific columns that I want and subset, it mostly works except "user" has sub categories (user.name, user.location) and if I add user, it will add all of these and I can't specify to keep location and not name for example.

Comment: I edited the example JSON to include some whole lines.

Comment: margusl, I added the bracket based on my research about a different error I was receiving. I added one and the beginning and end, I'll remove.

Comment: I don't seem to be able to reproduce those issues with streamed reads. When saving provided lines to a file named `file_sample` and using streamed read with either `twitter_a <- jsonlite::stream_in(file("file_sample"))` or `twitter_b <- ndjson::stream_in("sample.ndjson")`, results seems fine and Viewer does not complain ; former does not flatten by default and latter returns data.table by default, also seems about 3x faster.  Total file size is around 35MB as line count might suggest, and not in gigabytes?

Answer (score 1):

Your file is not valid json. However, each line on its own is valid json. This is known as [jsonl](https://www.atatus.com/glossary/jsonl/):

> JSONL is a text-based format that uses the .jsonl file extension and is essentially the same as JSON format except that newline characters are used to delimit JSON data. It also goes by the name JSON Lines.

Essentially the approach with jsonl files is to read the file in line by line, parse the json and then bind it together. I prefer [`rlist::list.flatten()`](https://rdrr.io/cran/rlist/man/list.flatten.html) to the `flatten` option in `jsonlite`, as the latter does not necessarily return a completely flat list.

Even using `list.flatten()`, with your data some columns can contain more than one value (e.g. `"indices":[3,13]` in line 1 of the text you provided). This can create duplicate rows.

We can avoid this by creating list columns, and using [`tibble::tibble_row()`](https://tibble.tidyverse.org/reference/tibble.html), which is guaranteed to create a one row tibble.

The function expects arguments in the form `tibble_row(a = 1, b = 2)`. We can use the `!!!` [splice](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/splice-operator.html) operator to provide the arguments from the list in this form, once we've made sure that any columns with length > 1 are list columns.

```r
library(rlang) # for the !!! (splice) operator
txt <- readLines("/Users/malana/Downloads/tweets.20130201_055232.10000lines")

lapply(txt, \(line) {
    dat <- rlist::list.flatten(jsonlite::fromJSON(line))
    # Make columns with length > 1 into list columns
    list_cols <- names(dat)[lengths(dat) > 1]
    dat[list_cols] <- lapply(dat[list_cols], list)
    # Create a row
    tibble::tibble_row(!!!dat)
}) |>
    dplyr::bind_rows()

# There are some more columns not shown here
# A tibble: 4 × 101
#   created_at                    id id_str text  source truncated user.id user.id_str user.name user.screen_name user.location user.description user.protected user.followers_count
#   <chr>                      <dbl> <chr>  <chr> <chr>  <lgl>       <int> <chr>       <chr>     <chr>            <chr>         <chr>            <lgl>                         <int>
# 1 Fri Feb 01 05:54:47 +00… 2.97e17 29722… RT @… "<a h… FALSE      1.06e9 1055846485  Arturo C… CamerasLara      "Tapachula C… "Gran visión pa… FALSE                            41
# 2 Fri Feb 01 05:54:47 +00… 2.97e17 29722… RT @… "<a h… FALSE      2.08e8 207797664   Bazinga   ferchug22        ""            "No llores por … FALSE                            28
# 3 Fri Feb 01 05:54:47 +00… 2.97e17 29722… #Som… "<a h… FALSE      7.25e8 724874196   Morgan✌❤  MorganAuderer    ""            "If nothing goe… FALSE                           212
# 4 Fri Feb 01 05:54:47 +00… 2.97e17 29722… @nac… "<a h… FALSE      9.82e8 982494234   さきんち… sakincho_s2      ""             NA              FALSE                            50
```